# How do I create a detach commit by accident?

Tags: git

I know that a detach commit can be created while in the detached HEAD state.
But how are these commits created because of the work of the git itself? I mean unintentionally.
I heard that it has to do with the immutability of commits...

Comment: Note: "detach(ed) commit" is not a [term of art](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/term%20of%20art) in Git. I think that, as in [Mark Adelsberger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64064595/1256452), you mean *unreachable commit*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're just asking how you end up with a commit that isn't reachable from any branch.  There are many ways.

If you use `commit --amend`, you can't *really* amend a commit.  Instead a new commit is made just like it would be without `--amend`, except with a different parent list.  (If `P` would be the parent for a regular commit, then `P`s parent list is copied and used as the new commit's parent list.)  Then the current branch is moved to the new commit, from which `P` is unreachable (since it wasn't used as a parent).  Unless `P` is still reachable from some other branch, it is what you are calling a "detach commit".

Or you could rebase, rewriting any number of commits.  Again "rewriting" means creating new commits, and a typical rebase might move a branch and leave the original commits unreachable.

Or you can use `git reset` to "un-commit" changes; again, the commit isn't really deleted, it just becomes unreachable.

Or you can simply delete a branch.

Or you can perform various oprations with `filter-branch` or similar tools.

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say that `--amend` creates a new commit with the same parent list as the commit it replaces.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood. There really can be many examples.

Comment: @chepner - since the commit it "replaces" *is* the commit that would be the parent of a normal commit, I'm not sure how that's supposed to be more accurate.  In fact since saying it "replaces" the commit is not precisely true except under certain (admittedly common) assumptions, I think my phrasing is the more accurate.

Comment: What do you mean, "normal commit"? If you have a history like `A -- B -- C` and you use `git commit --amend` to "amend" `C`, you are creating a new commit `D` that has the same parent(s) as `C`. Though it's fair to say `C` isn't replaced, since your current branch head will simply be `D` instead of `C`. (If `C` is no longer referenced by *anything*, then it is subject to garbage collection.)